# Disabling home folder symbol (~) in command line prompt

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, bashrc

How can I set Bash so that in the command line prompt the home folder is spelled out (e.g. `/Users/John`) instead of displayed with the `~` symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `.bashrc`, look for `PS1`. Replace `\w` with `$PWD` or `$(pwd -P)`, then run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the file.

(`$PWD` contains the shell's idea of the working directory, some parts of the path may be symbolic links. `$(pwd -P)` gets the "physical" path, with intervening symlinks resolved.)

Comment: Using `$PWD` instead of a command substitution would be more efficient.

Comment: I use the command because of an alias to `pwd -P`.